# Grails ClassPath Error, when update to 3.2.1

Tags: grails, groovy

After upgrading from `3.1.12 to 3.2.1` I get the following error:
Error:

```
  ClassPathScanner - The application defines a Groovy source using    the  default package. Please move all Groovy sources into a package.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.ConfigSupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

The message seems clear, but I cannot find any source which don't have a package.
Can any body help me either with a solution or an idea how to debug it.

Thanks

Comment: please run "grails clean-all" command then run "grails run-app" command .http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Command%20Line/clean-all.html

Comment: its grails clean since 3>, but it doesn't help, same error message

Comment: have you tried grails refresh dependencies command.

Comment: same thing its an old grails 2 command

Answer (score 6):

It's probably `BootStrap.groovy` (under grails-app/init) or `UrlMappings.groovy` (under grails-app/controllers)

Comment: not in this case though. They are both in the default package

Comment: Try running  `grails console` and running `ctx.grailsApplication.allClasses.findAll { !it.getPackage() }*.name`

Comment: getting the same error when I use grails console the application does not start.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you also had an error (the package thing is just a warning) and that the app isn't starting. Try commenting out any gorm and hibernate jars from the dependencies block until the app or console starts, and if the app still doesn't start with all dependencies active after resolving the package problem ask that as another question since it's not related to the package warnings

Answer (score 5):

I had same error as OP @Torsten.

Per @Burt Beckwith's suggestion,  ran `grails console` and `ctx.grailApplication.....` . It showed Bootstrap. So I moved `Bootstrap.groovy` from `grails-app/init` folder to `grails-app/init/my/package/name` folder where `Application.groovy` was.

When re-ran `grails run-app` the `ClassPathScanner....` error is gone !

Thanks OP and Burt Beckwith to post question and answer. It helped me.

PS: I wanted to add comment to Burt BeckWith's answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: That helped thanks. The ClassPath error is gone. Now I only get 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/gorm/plugin/support/ConfigSupport

Comment: I am not getting that error. Looks like something to do with database config? Do you have all dependencies defined in build.gradle ? Currently, I am migrating from 2.x to 3.2.1 .